# How to rationalise an integral $\int \frac{\sqrt{3 + 2x - x^2}}{x + \sqrt{3 + 2x - x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$3 + 2x - x^2 = - (x + 1)(x - 3)$, so I've already tried the substitution 
$$t = \sqrt{\frac{-1(x + 1)}{x  - 3}}$$ and also $t = \sqrt{3 + 3x - x^2}$. But seems it doesn't work in this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Substitute $$\sqrt{3+2x-x^2}=xt+\sqrt{3}$$ this is the Euler substitution.

Comment: Should i post you the solution?